# Create a continuing line graph in C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

I am showing the user data on their network speeds in C#

but I also want to show it plotted on a graph every second or so to show the high's and low's.

Does anyone know how to do this, sorry if I haven't made myself clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend checking out this moving line chart with automatic scaling by Andre de Cavaignac:
http://decav.com/blogs/andre/archive/2007/08/25/live-updating-line-graph-in-wpf.aspx